# Real time progress with ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am using **asp.net mvc 4.0 razor**

In my controller , i have 5 stored procedure to execute on clicking a button. The process is working fine. but each procedure takes 30-60 seconds to execute. in this time , i can show a .GIF image(processing...) with the help of javascript. But I have to show a **message** after finishing execution of each SP somewhere in my view page. like :

1. "dbExcel is processing"
2. "dbExcel process completed"
3. "dbCSV is processing"
4. "dbCSV process completed"
   .................................
   .................................

I have learnt that i have to do this with **ajax**. I know nothing about this and i have a short time that i cannot study ajax well and find a solution myself. I want a simple guideline that i can solve this matter.

Comment: Please ease up with the bolding. It doesn't help you convey your question, and is very distracting. Not my downvote, though.

Comment: This is not a simple problem.  If you're not willing to put in a fair amount of time and effort then you won't be able to solve this problem.

Comment: maybe your understanding is not accurate. i shared a timeline of my work and that is short.@AlexFilipovici

Comment: I have to do it anyway :) @Servy

Comment: @decoyer That's fine, just prepared to actually do some work and not expect a simple easy solution, because there is no *easy* solution.

Comment: i was not expecting a solution. "I want a simple guideline" of you experts.@Servy

Comment: Watch this [video series](http://pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro).

Answer (score 1):

Servicing Ajax calls in MVC is simple enough.  You can define actions in a controller that return data in JSON format instead of as a page view, and call those actions from JavaScript using jQuery or similar.

Here's an example controller method to get the current time as Ticks:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
...

    public JsonResult GetTicks()
    {
        return Json(DateTime.Now.Ticks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And the jQuery call to invoke it:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "/Home/GetTicks", 
    cache: false, 
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

You can use this technique to poll your server for current status of the long-running task and display the results on your page.  I'd create two controller actions - one to start the task running in a worker thread, the other to report on the progress of the task.

I strongly suggest using something like Firebug to examine the network request/response data for your ajax calls.  It helped me a lot when I was starting with this stuff.